# Cytoscape.js: Convert a rendered position to a model position

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

How can I convert a [rendered position](http://js.cytoscape.org/#notation/position) to a [model position](http://js.cytoscape.org/#notation/position)?

Example:

```
var rpos = cy.pan(); 
var mpos = cy.toModelPosition(rpos); // Get top left corner position in model
```

To my knowledge, the [doc](http://js.cytoscape.org/) does not mention any conversion method. I believe it would be super useful!

Of course, I could write something myself:

```
function toModelPosition(pos) {
    return {
        x: (pos.x - cy.pan().x) / cy.zoom(),
        y: (pos.y - cy.pan().y) / cy.zoom(),
    };
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like @maxkfranz mentioned, most functions of the Cytoscape's API accept both formats.

But I needed the conversion for my own use. So here's what I ended up doing:

```
// Convert a rendered position to a model position
cy.toModelPosition = (pos) => {
    const pan = cy.pan();
    const zoom = cy.zoom();
    return {
        x: (pos.x - pan.x) / zoom,
        y: (pos.y - pan.y) / zoom,
    };
};
// Convert a model position to a rendered position
cy.toRenderedPosition = (pos) => {
    const pan = cy.pan();
    const zoom = cy.zoom();
    return {
        x: pos.x * zoom + pan.x,
        y: pos.y * zoom + pan.y,
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You generally don't need to convert them, because the functions in the api allow you to pass either value.